# How can I "snap scroll" and trigger the event when snapped?

Tags: javascript, css

I tried using `scroll-snap` CSS property which works well in terms of the representation.

but I need to trigger an event when scrolled/snapped. how can I do that?

Comment: Im not sure if there is event being triggered but you can probably use Intersection Observer naitve Api:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Mladen suggested, using the [`Intersection Observer Api`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) seems to (kinda) work.

(Seems buggy on latest Firefox -- when scrolling up, observer goes crazy and logs only first section -- works fine on latest Chrome)

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(elem => {
    if (elem.isIntersecting) {
      const text = elem.target.querySelector('h2').innerText;
      console.log('Ping! Visible: ', text);
    }
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(elem => observer.observe(elem));
```

```css
.scroller {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.scroller section {
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<article class="scroller">
  <section>
    <h2>Section one</h2>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Section two</h2>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Section three</h2>
  </section>
</article>
```

I don't know if there's another way.

Comment: Works fine for me with the latest Firefox on Mac.

Comment: Buggy in safari v16.5. I got three sections and every time i scroll from 1 to 2, it says 3, and every time i scroll from 3 to 2, it says 1.

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS Scroll Snap Module Level 2 specification defines two events `snapChanging` and `snapChanged`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scroll-snap-2/#snap-events). The first one is obviously triggered when scrolling away from a snap position and the latter when the scroll position got snapped. The latter obviously covers your use case.

Though, as of the time of posting this answer, the specification is an early draft and no browser supports those events.
So, as long as they are not available, you'll have to use some polyfill.